# Non empty finite set properties - Rudin's PMA Example 2.21.c/d

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In the examples in 2.21, it is mentioned that a nonempty finite set $\in \bf{R^{2}}$ is closed but not open nor perfect nor bounded.

As an example of a nonempty finite set, let us consider a singleton set $\in \bf{R^{2}}$.

Being a singleton, this cannot have any limit points going by the definition in 2.18.b - a point $p$ is a limit point of set $E$ if every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q \neq p : q \in E$.

Since a singleton has no other points, it cannot meet this definition. Since it has no limit point, it cannot meet the definition of a closed set in 2.18.d - $E$ is closed if every limit point of $E$ is in $E$.

So for the example of a singleton set, it does not seem to be the case that nonempty finite sets are closed.

This same line of reasoning can be extended to other (especially discrete) subsets of $\bf{R^{2}}$, especially the set of all integers (Example 2.21.d)

[image]

Comment: If $E$ has no limit points, then every limit point of $E$ is in $E$.

Comment: That's cheating.

Comment: @Ahron Why would you say that's cheating? It's just another _logical paradox_.

Comment: Oh, that was just a off the cuff remark because I spent a good few minutes to double check my reasoning and then to type it all out, and then it turned out that to be a silly thing like a *vacuous definition*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a set $A$ to be closed it must satisfy the following statement: "if $x$ is a limit point of $A$ then $x$ is in $A$."

If the set has no limit points, then the statement is true [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Then I think the statement in Rudin is missing the qualifier "if" in the definition of a limit point

Comment: @Ahron $A$ is closed if $A$ contains all of it's limit points. If $A$ has no limit point, then $A$ is vacuously closed.